# How to join tables with no primary key in rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, primary-key

I have two tables that both have no primary key. below is the two tables structure.

[image]

How can I use this in a join table on column date in rails ?

Meanwhile, Date columns are not unique in both tables.

Comment: do you know the join condition to be used?

Comment: Join Condition requires a Primary key.Without it you cant do.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding (which may be wrong), you need to use a Primary key, in order to identify foreign keys in Rails

---

**Foreign Keys**

However, you could try using the `association_foreign_key` and `foreign_key` arguments in your associations definitions ([only works for HABTM](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)):

```
#app/models/table_a.rb
Class TableA < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :table_b, foreign_key: "country_id", association_foreign_key: "hour"
end

#app/models/table_b.rb
Class TableA < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :table_a, foreign_key: "hour", association_foreign_key: "country_id" 
end

table_as_table_bs
hour | country_id
```

Would be so difficult to include an `id` column in your tables??